# Is it possible to introduce Java runtime type in Google Colab?

Tags: java, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to introduce Java runtime type in Google Colab?

- For example, my jupyter notebook contains java code, which was run using a java kernel, specifically, IJava
- So, can we change runtime type in Google Colab, to run java code in the notebook?

Answer (score 1):

As of writing this, the https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html mentions:

> **What about Python3? (or R, Scala, ...)**
>
> Colaboratory supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.6. We're aware that users are interested in support for other Jupyter kernels (eg R or Scala). We would like to support these, but don't yet have any ETA.

I've also tried using the "Connect to local runtime" option with the hopes it would let me use the kernels I have installed on my machine but had no luck with that either. So, unfortunately the answer looks like *not yet*.

Comment: The reason behind asking this question is that, we had used your IJava kernel in Jupyter notebook, which was hosted in mybinder. But now the notebook does not seem to connect to Java Kernel. Hence we are looking for alternatives like Google Colab for hosting java based jupyter notebooks. Anyways, thanks for your development on IJava kernel :) . Can you take a look into the issue we are facing? https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr-jupyter-notebooks/issues/4

Comment: Thanks, I made the modifications, now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, yes you can.  Here is a post that breaks the process down in more detail, but in short, you use the IJava kernel from @SpencerPark, also linked below.

**Instructions for installing and configuring the Java kernel**

- https://medium.com/@gmsharpe/jupyter-java-and-google-colab-7a2f7fb08808

**IJava**

- https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava